# How best to detect non-nonsensical text?

Tags: java, nlp, text-mining

My use case is I have incoming files. Some have a descriptive file name, while others have  collection of numbers and/or letters for the file name.

I am interested to know, what is a suitable way to detect when the file name is not an English word?

Are there any text mining paradigms that can do such a task?

Thanks

Comment: there is a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007912/how-to-detect-is-text-human-readable I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a look up table of English words, and when check the incoming words with you table. For this tree you can use this:

https://code.google.com/p/word2vec/

You just need to use the table of words in that. Anything in the table is a valid word.

Comment: I don't understand why you suggest to use word2vec. word2vec is used to compute semantic similarity between words...

Comment: yeah, it's not very appropriate.

Comment: You just need to use the table of words in that. Anything in the table is a valid word.

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the file name in possible words (using spaces, dashes, undescores or whatever is appropriate in your data), and then run the words through a dictionary. if 80% of the words are in English, this is probably a non-nonsensical name.

Example of list of words are numerous: this is [cmudict](https://svn.code.sf.net/p/cmusphinx/code/trunk/cmudict/cmudict.0.7a) and or in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824422/can-i-get-an-english-dictionary-word-list-somewhere)